# Returning 2 column collections via postgres in spring jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, common-table-expression

I have a query that works with 2 tables to return 2 pieces of information: an object of the first table (t1) and a list of objects from the 2nd table (t2) that are related to the first object. So, the output should be an array of `{t1,List<t2>}`. Both outputs are evaluated via CTEs and not all columns from db tables are present in t1 & t2 (since some of them are not required). The query I have is as so:

```
    @Query(value=
        "WITH t1 AS " +
            "(...), " +
        "t2 AS " +
            "(...) " +
        "SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1, t2 " +
        "WHERE t2.my_id in " +
            "(SELECT entity_table.my_id FROM entity_table " +
            "WHERE entity_table.num = t1.num)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> myQuery();
```

Now, at the moment my query returns all columns from t1,t2 as individual entries of `Object[]` array. In other words, instead of having only 2 objects in my array (1st be t1 and 2nd be a list of t2's), I have an array that contains multiple objects i.e. t1.col1,t1.col2,...,t2.col1,t2.col2,... . I don't want that. I want this query only have 2 objects in my array - 1st entry having all columns of t1 and 2nd entry having all columns of t2.

Initially, I though I can modify my query to use multiple `INTO` statements, so that my `SELECT` part of the query would be as so:

```
SELECT t1.* INTO t1 FROM t1, t2.* INTO t2 FROM t2
```

But from what I understand you cannot have more than one `INTO` clause in one SELECT statement.

I also tried to utilise `UNION` clause but the catch here is that my outputs are related (in my subquery you can see that I filter t2 using a column from t1).

So my question is: how can one return a multiple collections of columns when doing a `select` operation?

Comment: Are these tables mapped to entities?

Comment: No, t1 & t2 do not have entities associated with them. They are just temp result sets produced by CTEs (unlike entity_table that I mentioned in the last sub-query - this one does have entity class + actual table in db).

Answer (score 0):

Your query just returns a table like structure.
There is no information there that you want to group the `ResultSet` in a way to yield one `t1` and an array of `t2`.
Since these columns aren't even mapped to classes `t1` and `t2` doesn't even have a meaning on the Java side of things.

You could try to use [Postgre's `ARRAY_AGG`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg/) function to actually construct the result structure you are looking for.
Though I'm not sure what kind of array you'd get back.
Probably not a Java array, but a [JDBC Array type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html).

The alternative is to write a custom method implementation, end employ a `JdbcTemplate` and [`ResultSetExtractor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html)